# DropdownList reset to to index 0 on load

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, reload

How would I reset my `asp:DropDownList` element (which has a `runat="server"`) to index 0 every time the page is "reloaded" in Firefox (F5 is pressed)?

If you suggest using JavaScript, please note that

- I am not using a form
- I don't know how to access elements that have a `runat="server"` with JavaScript

If this can be done using script on the `.aspx` page then please explain.

Answer (score 9):

put code in the [Page_Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) event to do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    myDropDownList.SelectedIndex =0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comments, If you have put the above logic inside of an if statement to check whether `Page.IsPostback = false`, then the selected index will not be set back to 0 upon refresh (which performs a client postback). As an example to demonstrate this, here is a page with a dropdown list set to autopostback upon selection

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Apologies for Dairy Produce inspired list
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Cheese"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yoghurt"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Milk"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Butter"));
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Run the Page with this in first, then comment out
        //the if statement to leave only ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

As will be demonstrated, when the page is originally ran, upon refresh, the selected index will be retained within the dropdown list; When the `if` statement is commented out however, upon refresh, the selected index is set to 0 (which in this case is *Cheese*).

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. It doesn't work...the DropdownList seems to be reset to it's previous selection by the cache.

Not that is should make a difference but I put this command int he "If Page.IsPostBack = False"  statement

Comment: It could either be in a code-behind file (preferred approach) or within script tags in aspx markup (akin to Classic ASP). The likely source of a previous index would be Viewstate, but that gets set in Pre_Load and would be overridden by the above statement.

Comment: If you put this inside if Page.IsPostback = false, then the statement will only run when the page is first loaded, not in response to a client postback, which is what a refresh would be

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to your Page_Load event :

```
if (myDropDown.Items.Count > 0)
{
    myDropDown.Items[myDropDown.SelectedIndex].Selected = false;
    myDropDown.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Already tried this. doesn't work. if you check the SelectedIndex of dropdownlist in the Page_load it returns 0....but a different index is visible...i think the browser cache resets it after the code executes (i am using firefox)   ..i assume you mean from the code behind?

Comment: A lot of years later, and this answer helped me when the accepted answer didn't work for some reason. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

In your script under code HTML:

```
B01 = document.getElementById('<%=me.yourID.clientid %>');
B01.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Happy Coding ^^

Answer (score 1):

stop Firefox from retaining the viewstate and repopulating the form:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Firefox")
            Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
    }
```